# knockout paging retaining old page on jquery dialog cancel and open

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, knockout.js

I have an issue with knockout paging .I am using knockout paging on jquery dialog.The issue is when i navigate from page1 to page2 ,page3 or page4 and close the dialog and open the dialog again i see the page which i  closed last  but not from first page .Attached the jsfiddle below.Please let me know if you have any questions.

http://jsfiddle.net/bharatgillala/yuvNt/57/

```
    var data = [
        {Player:"PAGE1", runs:"34889"},
        {Player:"PAGE1", runs:"83366"},
        {Player:"PAGE1", runs:"52534"},
        {Player:"PAGE2", runs:"02232"},
        {Player:"PAGE2", runs:"55899"},
        {Player:"PAGE2", runs:"90483"},
        {Player:"PAGE3", runs:"02565"},
        {Player:"PAGE3", runs:"98500"},
        {Player:"PAGE3", runs:"20285"},
        {Player:"PAGE4", runs:"57757"},
    ];
       var StaticDataExample1 = function(data){
       // stuff I care about
       this.items = ko.observableArray(data);

    // pager related stuff
       ------------------------------
        this.currentPage = ko.observable(1);
        this.perPage = 3;
        this.pagedItems = ko.computed(function(){
        var pg = this.currentPage(),
            start = this.perPage * (pg-1),
            end = start + this.perPage;
        return this.items().slice(start,end);
        }, this);
        this.nextPage = function(){
        if(this.nextPageEnabled())
            this.currentPage(this.currentPage()+1);
        };
        this.nextPageEnabled = ko.computed(function(){
        return this.items().length > this.perPage * this.currentPage();
        },this);
        this.previousPage = function(){
        if(this.previousPageEnabled())
            this.currentPage(this.currentPage()-1);
         };
        this.previousPageEnabled = ko.computed(function(){
        return this.currentPage() > 1;
    },this);
   };

ko.applyBindings(new  StaticDataExample1(data),document.getElementById("test"));
       $(document).on("click", "[id*=atest]", function () 
       {
         $("#test" ).dialog(
       {
        height: 420,
        width: 430,
        modal: true,   
        buttons: [
        {
            text: "Save",
        },
       {
           text: "Cancel",
           tabIndex: -1,
           click: function () {
               $(this).dialog("close");
           }
       }
        ],     
        close: function () { }
        });
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there actually.

Change your ko.applyBindings to this:

```
var model = new StaticDataExample1(data);
ko.applyBindings(model, document.getElementById("test"));
```

Then add an `open:` function to your `$(...).dialog({ ... })` options right after the `close:` option:

```
    close: function () {
    },
    open: function () {
        model.currentPage(1);
    }
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/yuvNt/63/

And it occurred to me just now; you could even just add the `model.currentPage(1);` call into your existing `close:` function if you don't want to add an `open:` function.

Hope that's useful.

Comment: Thanks Paul ..Even i tried setting currentpage value to 1 . but i tried in a different way model.currentPage = ko.observable(1) //wrong way i know ..I missed some thing there..